# update an array of tuples with certain index

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tuples

I am stuck trying to update my multidimensional array. First, I filter for a certain string called title, which serves as my identifier. Then I want to replace the value for description for this filtered array.

I have already tried to solve this issue with something like `rowContent[1] = descriptionTranferred` (value at index 1, which is description, shall be replaced by value in descriptionTranferred). I also tried `rowContent.description = descriptionTranferred`, but it was not successful either.

Is there any way to update the description value in my array?

Here is my code:

**SWIFT 3**

```
var rowContent = Array<(title: String, description: String)>()


func transferData(descriptionTranferred: String, identifier: String) {
    if rowContent.contains(where: {$0.title == identifier}) {

        rowContent[1] = descriptionTranferred

    } else {
        print ("nothing")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a multidimensional array but array of tuples with named parameters. Try:

```
rowContent[1].description = descriptionTranferred
```

But I'm guessing that you're trying to change description in tuple on index that matches identifier so replace your `if` condition:

```
if let index = rowContent.index(where: {$0.title == identifier}) {
    rowContent[index].description = descriptionTranferred
}else {
    print ("nothing")
}
```

Comment: Your solution works perfekt! And yes, you are also right with the tuples... I was so confused at some point I did not realize I was using an array of tuples.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you're missing an opening `{` on your function :p

```
var rowContent = Array<(title: String, description: String)>()

func transferData(descriptionTranferred: String, identifier: String) {
    if rowContent.contains(where: {$0.title == identifier}) {
        rowContent[1] = descriptionTranferred
    } else {
        print ("nothing")
    }
}
```

In the line `rowContent[1] = descriptionTranferred`, you're trying to assign `descriptionTranferred` (a `String`), to `rowContent[1]`, which is a tuple of `(title: String, description: String)`.

You need to assign the string to the correct component of the tuple:

```
rowContent[1].description = descriptionTranferred
```

This code is likely going to crash. You're always setting the `description` of the row at index `1`, without any consideration of its title. Perhaps you meant to set the description for every row where `title == identifier`?

```
func transferData(descriptionTranferred: String, identifier: String) {
    let rowsToUpdate = rows.filter{ $0.title == identifier }

    if rowsToUpdate.isEmpty {
        print("No rows to update.")
        return
    }

    for var row in rowsToUpdate {
        row.description = descriptionTranferred
    }
}
```

That'll make it "work", but it's sub-optimal. You shouldn't be using tuples for this purpose. Structs are a much more appropriate data structure for this data:

```
struct RowContent { //TODO: needs better name
    let title: String
    var description: String
}

var rows = [RowContent]()

func transferData(descriptionTranferred: String, identifier: String) {
    let rowsToUpdate = rows.filter{ $0.title == identifier }

    if rowsToUpdate.isEmpty {
        print("No rows to update.")
        return
    }

    for var row in rowsToUpdate {
        row.description = descriptionTranferred
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I will restructure my code like you suggested, since it will get more complicated in the future. Implementing a structure is definitely the right thing to do!

Comment: Yep. You'll find this buys you a more flexibility. Structs can conform to protocols and do all kinds of great polymorphic and generic fun stuff.

Comment: Also, structs are more strongly typed than tuples. Fundamentally, your `(title: String, descriptions: String)` tuple is the same type as any other `(String, String)` tuple. There's nothing stopping me from assigning my `(FirstName: String, LastName: String)` tuple to a place where you expect your title/description